# How do I code a GUI Selection Box?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, html

I want to build into my app a way to select multiple objects on the screen (this is an HTML page with a bunch of absolutely positioned HTML divs). You know, like when you click down with the mouse and drag a transparent/translucent box and anything within that box gets selected upon mouse release?

I don't know how to go about coding that. How would you? Or pointers to solutions is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) javascript library. It has an extension [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) that provides abstractions for interaction and animation. For drag an drop you have: [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Comment: +1 This sort of thing is tricky to get right.  Better to use an existing, well tested solution rather than reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.

Mousedown creates a high z-index div, transparent body with a nice border, which has its dimensions informed by mousemove. On mouseup you compare the region of that div with applicable elements. This wouldn't be particularly hard to do without a library, but YUI3 makes it pretty simple, have a look at http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/Node.html#method_inRegion

HTH.